# Set the (default) encoding of a SQLite database through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, encoding

I want to create a SQLite database through the python driver. As the application will run on different operating systems I want to explicitly specify the (default) encoding of text within the SQLite database.

Apparently I can only do this before a database is created with this command [(see SQLite docs)](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding):

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

My problem is that the Python way to create/connect to a database does not specify (at least to my understanding) a way to set PRAGMAs (such as encoding) before the database is created ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects))

Is there therefore any way to specify the encoding through the python SQlite driver before/while a database is created?

The only workaround I currently see, which seems a bit hacky, is to run Shell commands through python, but since the SQLite CLI is not installed on the machines, this is no option.

Comment: The closest I can think of is the [`text_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory) but you would already have created the DB in instantiating a connection. In fact, my suggestion may be less suitable for what you're trying to do, but it's something to look at I guess

Comment: @roganjosh I thought about that, but text factory is a gateway between the application and the database. So I could not control what the database saves (in which encoding) but only how I read the data.... At least if I understood correctly

Comment: They have C API https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: From what I can see, `PRAGMA encoding` is a one-shot, permanent change to the whole database. Connecting to the DB and executing the PRAGMA _should_ do what you're looking for for all subsequent tables. That being the case, it doesn't look like the API has any other provision for it

Comment: No, I'm angling more towards your interpretation now, going to try test some things out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the database and change the encoding afterwards

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('pragma encoding')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fa641241e30>
>>> rows = c.fetchall()
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
... 
('UTF-8',)
>>> c.execute('pragma encoding=UTF16')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fa641241b20>
>>> c.execute('pragma encoding')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fa641241e30>
>>> rows = c.fetchall()
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
... 
('UTF-16le',)
```

Note that it is required to edit the database to make these changes permanent, eg:

```
>>> sql_create_projects_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (
...                                         id integer PRIMARY KEY,
...                                         name text NOT NULL,
...                                         begin_date text,
...                                         end_date text
...                                     ); """
>>> c.execute(sql_create_projects_table)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f441ce90e30>
>>> rows = c.fetchall()
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
...
>>> sql = ''' INSERT INTO projects(name,begin_date,end_date)
...               VALUES(?,?,?) '''
>>> project = ('Cool App with SQLite & Python', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-30');
>>> c.execute(sql, project)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f441ce90e30>
```

If you do not at least add a table, the encoding will fall back to its default. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't get it to work: https://pastebin.com/4Dst51Fd. The encoding only holds for a single session and it's just going back to UTF-8. It's already gone back to UTF-8 before I try to change it

Comment: Hi it worked for me, try adding a table and data after this step before closing it

Comment: Close your connection, reestablish it and then see if you get the same result. You run this all in one session.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XBfnnjeV here it is with some fake data. Still the same encoding after closing / reestablishing the connection

Comment: Seems to work for me (if I add a table). That seems to make the encoding change permanent. I'll experiment a bit more and will mark the answer accepted if it still works

Comment: @JonathanR Your example works for me and I would mark it as the accepted solution. Could you edit your answer to include the create a table "hack"?